# Do .NET threads inherit their priority from the creating thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading

Do .NET threads inherit their priority from the creating thread?

What if i span a thread inside a thread with higher priority than parent?

Comment: The only parent of a thread is a process. They's all siblings. Only processes have a hierarchical relationship.

Comment: Surely you could answer this with a simple test o.O https://gist.github.com/ByteBlast/5b06b8fc4bba74556051

Comment: Why don't you just try this yourself?  The Thread.Priority property is readily available, shouldn't take you more than a few minutes to check it yourself.  [Use the science!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Your premise needs to be re-examined; when you spawn a new thread, it's not considered to be "inside" another thread.  It is simply added to a list of *all* running threads, inside the current process.

Answer (score 2):

Threads are all created with the default (normal) priority, priority must be set explicitly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadStart ts = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(RunFirst);
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread( ts);
        t.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
        t.Start();
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void RunFirst()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("First Thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority.ToString());
        System.Threading.ThreadStart ts = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(RunChild);
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(ts);
        t.Start();


    }
    public static void RunChild()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Child: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority.ToString());

    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
First Thread: BelowNormal
Child: Normal
```